# "Oh The Horror" Hat Club 2013

Tags: discussion, winterbash-2013

41 people join in.

Each person upvotes every answer, other than theirs, to this question.

Once we have 41 answers and votes, I will systematically accept each answer in turn.

41 people get the "Oh the Horror" <strike>and "Marauder"</strike> hat<strike>s</strike>.

Easy.

---

Note: as @Gilles has noted, we can't get the Marauder hat in Meta.
You can, however, answer [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142142/what-is-a-marauder) and I will award you the marauder hat.  Ping me on chat if you haven't got it yet.

Comment: 41 people should consider getting a life. (I *am* including myself, before you get all grumpy.)

Comment: I am on a train for five hours.  I plan on spending it finding hats.  And I have no shame in that!

Comment: There are no hats on meta sites, so you can't get the Marauder hat here. “Oh the Horror” is gained on the main site for something that happens on the meta site, but Marauder has to happen on the main site. You could do this on [metase] though: it counts as [so]'s meta (so you can get “Oh the Horror” on SO), and it doubles as the SE meta which is a proper site, so there are hats there as well.

Comment: As I [wrote before](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/has-anyone-on-elu-been-awarded-the-i-see-your-point-hat-yet#comment14498_4345), I will only vote for something witty. Try a pun, a haiku, or a limerick. Only good ones need apply.

Comment: I don’t care to belong to any club that will have me as a member.

Comment: We appear to be a few hats short of a rack.

Comment: @snailboat Make that an answer so I can vote it up! I actually giggled. Thankfully, I got a second hat so that I will not need to wear a menorah on my head. It got tangled in my tusks :o)

Comment: Atwood better not have lice...

Comment: I knew it would happen! Now we're all going to catch [millinophilia][1] and die!


  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142420/a-name-for-hat-collectors/142428#comment292316_142420

Comment: Houston, we have a problem.

Comment: As a side note: this is give-and-take. You get a hat out of this, you better help others. I am seeing 37 answers, so one would expect them all to have roughly 36 votes. Some are still in the single numbers, though.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Christmas is the time for giving a life, not for getting one d-;

Comment: Please can all participants of this hat club vote up all other answers?  I want to get these hats out of the door!

Comment: Right - that's me in atr number 41. Upvoting begins now :-)

Comment: I'm whoring for upvotes again.  Votes here would be greatly received!  http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Who would refuse a free hat? Actually, quite a few people would, but not me.

Answer (score 46):

The first rule of Hat Club is...

**Everyone in Hat Club talks about Hat Club.**

Right now I'm wearing the boat hat.  This works out well for me because snail and also boat.  Unfortunately, there are no hats on meta :-(

Bonus <strike>haiku</strike> senryū:

> 俳句をね
>   面倒くさい
>   ムズすぎよ

Comment: I would have upvoted your answer for free! snail*boat*. Ha!

Comment: *Haiku-wo ne / Mendou kusai / muz sugi yo* . . . ? 難しいぞ。

Comment: Chelmsford? I lived for a time in Tewskbury.

Comment: Yay!  I'm an official member of Hat Club now!

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 45):

Your ideas are intriguing to me, and I wish to subscribe to your newsletter.

Comment: That's hilarious.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

Well, if you are selling hats, then I consider this the perfect business opportunity, because I am buying hats.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Answer (score 45):

**Forty**, you say?  Forty’s not so much, [provided that they’re only goblins, as any bear can tell you](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/142821/):

> ‘. . . I killed a goblin or two with a flash—’
>
> ‘Good!’ growled Beorn. ‘It is some good being a wizard, then.’
>
> ‘— and slipped inside the crack before it closed. I followed down into the main hall, which was crowded with goblins. The Great Goblin was there with thirty or ***forty*** armed guards. I thought to myself “even if they were not all chained together, what can a dozen do against so many?” ’
>
> ‘A dozen! That’s the first time I’ve heard eight called a dozen. Or have you still got some more jacks that haven't yet come out of their boxes?’

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: @Ste I did that long ago. It was my idea to do so.

Comment: Cheers!  I was just spamming everyone!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 45):

> There are many times when a woman will ask another girl friend how she likes her new hat. She will reply, 'Fine,' but slap her hand to her forehead the minute the girl leaves to yipe, 'What a horror!'

-- Marilyn Monroe

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: @Ste done. Happy New Year.

Answer (score 45):

Mmmm, smells good. Is it hat yet?

Hey, while we're waiting, how about a little [Leopard-Skin Pillbox Hat](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ErGhY4yUYU8)?

Comment: *some like it hat and some sweat when the hat is on...*

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

I think that this is a fantastic idea.  In fact, now that I am in, we only need 40 others.

Comment: I’m thinking that either you cannot give it to yourself and earn the hat, or perhaps it cannot be a CW answer — or both.

Comment: @tchrist. It [can be a CW answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61683/how-close-am-i-to-the-guru-badge/61688#61688), but it cannot be a self-accept.

Answer (score 44):

If we do that we could lose our upvoting capacity for real questions, mightn't we? isn't it limited ? 
Have a safe journey, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you will use your maximum if you do it in a day but you get a hat for that too!  I'm expecting this one to take a few days to reach maximum hatocity though.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Answer (score 44):

Sign me in! 
It is interesting that though I tried to qualify for some (secret?) hats on English & Usage site looks like without a single post (or maybe an answer) I can't get any hat.

Comment: Hats are awarded only for the specific activities they are awarded for. All you need is an account. Posts are not required. I myself have hundreds of hats on sites I never posted anything to. Not an answer, not a question, not a single comment.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

I've got nothing better to do today anyway, I guess.

... but won't we need 41?  Can't upvote your own answer.

Comment: Good point. I shall edit.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

This is indeed a great idea.  I am in!

So, if I'm reading the Guru badge requirements right, does this mean you plan to accept all the answers in turn?

(Even if the hat thing doesn't work, this club will at least generate a bunch of badges.)

**Edit:** *Ah, throwing in the Marauder hat confirms the game plan.*

Comment: Yep, which is why I have now advertised "Two hats for the price of one" in [chat here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12778202#12778202)

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

Haaaaats! And I've always wanted a pirate hat.

Dunno if I want Jeff Atwood's hair, though. Is that a required part of this endeavor?

Comment: No you can own a hat without it ever touching a follicle.

Comment: @Ste: Well, Martha has a whole bunch of hats already. Not as many as you, but plenty. Maybe she specifically doesn't want it in her hat rack. Perhaps you can just accept her answer when you go through accepting answers (so she gets the Marauder) and other kind folks can *not* upvote this answer... (I lack the restraint and have already upvoted).

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: @Ste: 'tis done.

Comment: Why thank you.  :o)

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

We've gone too far. We might as well continue into the darkness.

Comment: Outwardly I'm laughing, but inwardly...

Comment: It echoes! It echoes!

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

Not being witty enough to pass muster, I take the lazy man's way out. Oh, and I'm in. The quote should be gender neutral.

> "There are very few moments in a man's existence when he experiences so much ludicrous distress, or meets with so little charitable commiseration, as when he is in pursuit of his own hat."

Charles Dickens, The Pickwick Papers

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

It'll never work... Count me in!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 44):

A young man sat down by the waters
his thought, to create some Marauders
He posted his plan
And so it began
To work, though, the scope must be broader.

Comment: You now have the hat.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: @Ste-  Cool Thanks.  You have been upvoted.

Answer (score 43):

An interesting experiment in hat-testing-to destruction (is there a single word for that?).

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 43):

There was an old person of Fratton
Who would go to the church with his hat on.
'If I wake up,' he said,
'With a hat on my head,
I will know that it hasn't been sat on.'

Comment: You now have your hat.

Comment: Now that you have your hat, please return the favour by [***clicking here*** and ***upvoting my answer***](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4344/20739).  Then I can have the hat like you! Thanks!

Comment: @Ste. Thanks. I'd already upvoted that answer. Looks like you need to work on your Mr. Binx!

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 43):

Please save me from having no alternative other than wearing a menorah on my head! That is my only hat at the present time. I would like a better hashed haberdashery.

That makes no sense, none at all. I apologize. I covet StackExchange hats.

Answer (score 42):

I'm not a hat hater, I just don't like SE hats. (My answer will make it 20 which is my favorite number.)

Answer (score 42):

If this is not a great idea, I don't know what is!
Lucky me, there is still room.

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 42):

Wow. I'm almost out of votes for the day here. This better work!

> There was an epic cornet.
>
> With a hat and a wig to get,
>
> He posted an answer
>
> and said he'd look fancier
>
> with a patch and cap to boot

Answer (score 42):

That's a lot of work. Will enough people really go to the trouble?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Have a hat from me.

Comment: Nice. A shock toupee.

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 41):

I'm answer No. 13. Which is fine, because in Italy it's 17 which brings ill fortune.

Please, may I have that black wig, the horror one, it gets so wearisome dying my hair. A wig would solve all my problems, ta very much!

Comment: Sorry it's so late.  Have a wig!

Comment: Thanks all the same :)

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 41):

Is this whole thing really a good idea?  Is this how we want posterity to remember us, grubbing after votes and slavishly pressing +1, +1, +1 ... for more than a whole minute?  And getting exposed to dangerous signs like "You haven't voted on questions in a while; questions need votes too"?

Comment: I have already said that I have no shame.  I am only two hats from the #1 spot on the network leaderboard.  But I like how you answer anyway and pretend you didn't want to really do it....  ;o)

Comment: (1). Yes. (2). But... More Hats! (3). See (2).

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Comment: @Ste, I've already upvoted all the other answers, but when I upvote this one I just get an error message and no upvote.

Comment: @jwpat7 No worries, I think we've done just about enough!

Answer (score 41):

I want a hat. I so want a hat. Hat me.

**Almost there!**

Oh, come on.

Comment: Stand by for your hat.

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 41):

I'm probably late to the party but, 'duh.

Comment: Good luck anyway :P

Comment: Have a hat from me...

Answer (score 41):

The hat that I had
would take a hit, but I hid
under a hood, that was hot in the hut.

Hot like hell, oh the horror!

Comment: Stand by for your hat.

Comment: @Ste: If I was to bow, like I feel inclined, the shiny new (ugly, really) hat would come off. And we wouldn't want that. :)

Comment: I shall permit you to kiss my hand this time.

Comment: How gracious, dear Sir! *smootch*

Comment: Sorry for more spam but please [upvote this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4420/20739) ***and*** the other answers to get EL&U some more hats.

Answer (score 41):

> Searchers after horror haunt strange, far places. -- H.P. Lovecraft, and everyone in this thread.

Answer (score 40):

Most of the answers to this questions are not answers and should be flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: Including this one!

Comment: Never said it wasn't...

Answer (score 39):

> I've been dressing up
>   as something I'm not
>   for so long...
>
> I'm so afraid you won't like
>   what's underneath.
>
> But here I am.
>   I'm just flesh and blood
>   and weakness.

Answer (score 39):

Hats! This is probably a bad idea...

Answer (score 39):

Hats? We don't need no stinking hats!

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote :P

Answer (score 39):

For want of a hat answered I this question.

Answer (score 39):

Ooh, can I join in?  One can never have too many hats, and there's so many hats, so little time!

Answer (score 38):

I think the first answer is nice, but I thought it was the *SECOND* rule of Hat Club. I'll have to watch Hat Club again to check.

Answer (score 36):

I'd settle for knowing just what the secret is behind Chuck Yeager.  I won it twice so far and am completely in the dark as to why...

ETA:  dang! I ran out of votes!   see y'all late tonite!

Comment: Chuck Yeager was the first man to fly faster than the speed of sound, so speed/quickness is likely involved. What have you done quickly on the sites?

Comment: @Jim that's my guess too, which is to say answering a question w/in some time after it was posted. Who knows..

Comment: @CarlWitthoft. I wouldn't want to bet on it, but I think you have to be first to answer, and then get at least two upvotes. If true, then [this answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90815) could have got you your Chuck Yeager on Physics.

Comment: Answer a question within 15 minutes of it getting posted, and be the first one to do so. You might or might not need get more than one upvote, too.

Comment: @RegDwigнt. Interesting, but I don't see how the 15 minute condition can be right. I got one on ELU, and none of my answers were within 20 minutes.

Comment: @ekhumoro truth be told, I don't know the exact figure. I thought it was five minutes at first. (Posting an answer within the grace period.) Then people started popping up with accounts of larger numbers. So 15 minutes was the one I could vow for as the upper limit at the time of my last comment's writing. It might well be 20 minutes, or 20 hours, even. I do not know. I'm just trying to provide safe figures, is all.

Answer (score 34):

I only voted on answers that had 41 or fewer votes already. I was too lazy to RTFQ.

Was I a good boy? Do I get a present?

Comment: @Susan: I'm only in it for the LOLs (-:

Answer (score 33):

I'm throwing my hat in the ring, too. Oh, whoops, I don't have a hat.

Comment: Do enable hats in [your profile](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/53907/rebecca). Otherwise you won't be able to wear them.

Comment: Welcome to Hat Club, @Rebecca!

Comment: @snailboat. I'm loving it, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

I am not clear on the rules and/or expectations.
Must a provided answer be witty, amusing, quotable, or intelligent in any way?

Comment: Well, this one certainly isn't :P

Comment: @AmericanLuke, does “this one” refer to your comment on the answer, or the answer?  Also, the answer is quite quotable; for example:  “I am not clear on the rules and/or expectations.
Must a provided answer be witty, amusing, quotable, or intelligent in any way?”

Answer (score 18):

Hmmmmm - I like it...

But it's soooo unethical :-)

Answer (score 17):

Want to see if this still works! :P :D

Answer (score 16):

MY KINGDOM FOR A HAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!