# Is there to be no end-of-year frivolity this year?

Tags: discussion

At the end of 2015, there was a welcome spurt of frivolity on ELU Meta.  I refer to [Shall we just toss the Winter Hats into the bin?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7427/shall-we-just-toss-the-winter-hats-into-the-bin) and [Please air your grievances here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7490/please-air-your-grievances-here).

I thought maybe this outburst of rampant off-topic-ness was a one time affair, regretted and deplored by the poohbahs of the site, but in 2013 there was ["Oh The Horror" Hat Club 2013](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/oh-the-horror-hat-club-2013).

Is this behavior biennial and not due to flower again until 2017?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bloody well hope so, 2016 has *not* been the cheeriest of years. Bring on the frolic and frivolity ☺ ☻ ♥ ♦ ♣ ♠ ○ ◘ • (I only discovered yesterday how to do 'em on the keyboard) ♂▬!,7BMXc

[image]

Possibly, the world's worst Christmassy hat ever.

### Merry Christmas EL&Uers

Comment: Inspiration for next year's hat selection.  I want one!

Comment: Hmm, multiple decorations. It'd be nice to be able to decorate one's avatar with more than just one hat when they're available. Also, a little belated, but ... Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Lawrence And a Merry one to you too.

Comment: @Lawrence: there's absolutely nothing belated about wishing someone Merry Christmas on the third day thereof. (My pet peeves about this season: 1. it's called a Christmas tree, not an Advent tree; if you're throwing it out on the 26th, you're Doing It Wrong(TM), and 2. You know those 12 days of Christmas you like singing about? The 12th day is a week into January. If you're turning off your Christmas lights before the new year, you're Doing It Wrong(TM).)

Comment: Merry Christmas, @Marthaª! :)

Comment: @Lawrence: See [Only wear one hat at a time?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/288436/195817)

Answer (score 5):

On the subject of hat-engendered frivolity, I offer you the papakhi, which I have just learned is "a male wool hat worn throughout the Caucasus."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hat_styles

Oh, and I just got a Yoda hat for "use the site's search functionality on 3 consecutive UTC days". May the force functionality be with me.

Comment: Also frivolous is the [fascinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hat_styles#/media/File:Chloe_Moo_of_Darwin_-_2013_Myer_Fashions_on_the_Field_(10705418974).jpg), pictured in your link. But the dagger the man wearing the [papakhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hat_styles#/media/File:Sunni_Muslim_man_wearing_traditional_dress_and_headgear_alt1.jpg) is holding looks serious

Comment: Welcome is your edit!

Answer (score 4):

Don't get me wrong, I like hats.  But what is more fundamental than a hat?  What underlies, supports and surrounds a hat?  *Hair.*  And if you don't think hair can outdo a hat, see [Extreme Hairstyles](https://www.google.com/search?q=extreme+hairstyles&biw=1237&bih=642&tbm=isch&imgil=mWh7rRpfplRfzM%253A%253BfkqtfWyBLfGTRM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Ftwirlit.com%25252F2013%25252F05%25252F20%25252F9-hilariously-extreme-hair-styles%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=mWh7rRpfplRfzM%253A%252CfkqtfWyBLfGTRM%252C_&usg=__z5mrSaxM0ZtubRVTnrVnibjsfy4%3D&ved=0ahUKEwjB4o3d0ZDRAhUFSCYKHe63ANkQyjcIKQ&ei=GGlgWMH2I4WQmQHu74LIDQ#q=extreme+hairstyles&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CZloe60aX6ZUIjh55Uc2NaVikl9rz8WmQ8e4KA6Vh1WCYPvf1ztO3axEJUoZxD9PRo-OpyGAMdyzvaodmVqttX4TRyoSCXnlRzY1pWKSEU7uSgER1lLLKhIJX2vPxaZDx7gRh8y77yjAXqYqEgkoDpWHVYJg-xFu5ewiZ6QQsSoSCd_1XO07drEQlEUfKpSznomjJKhIJShnEP09Gj44RXoXginEioY0qEgmnIYAx3LO9qhFpN7qMYBLl1SoSCR2ZWq21fhNHEf8oRKoceULb)

Answer (score 4):

To be completely boring and actually (part) answer your question: The 2015 Meta frivolity was caused by people trying to gain hats which required specific actions on Meta.

As there were no meta-based hats this year (that I can think of), people didn't flock to Meta.

Thank you for rectifying that with this question. :D

Comment: Let's hope that the [milliners](http://blog.thatwayhat.com/?p=219) rectify that omission in 2017.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some more deserving frivolity...

### Who wore it best?

[image][image][image][image]

No.1 Andrew Leach♦ No.2 David Richerby No.3 RedGrittyBrick and No.4 tchrist♦

Comment: Andrew Leach centered the beard best, and tchrist looks the most Leonardo-esque.

Answer (score 2):

Who wore it best? #3

[image][image]
[image] [image]

No.1 Mick; No.2 bleh; No. 3 Andy F; No.4 WS2

Comment: All of them have a lot of je ne said quoi, but bleh has the most chutzpah.

Answer (score 2):

Who wore it best? #4 
(last day of Winter Bash 2016)

[image][image]
[image] [image]

No.1 Andrew; No.2 StoneyB; No.3 snailplane ♦ (ELL) No.4 Catija

Comment: It's a tough choice between the pentapus and the snail.....

Answer (score 1):

### Who wore it best? #2

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

No.1 Hank;  No.2 Balpha; No.3 MetaEd♦; No. 4 Catija

Comment: How can one pick the most beautiful of these beauties?

Comment: I think they look simply ravishing.

Answer (score -5):

Frivolity? Please. This is a site for "linguists, etymologists, and *serious* English language enthusiasts." (Emphasis mine.) And if you don't believe me, you can seek confirmation from those in the first two categories.

If any of them ever show up.

Comment: Do you think users like John Lawler, Greg Lee and BillJ are not linguists? I think they are, and I'm happy we have them here. It's very likely I'm missing your rhetorical point when I point this out, but if I am then probably others are too.

Comment: @sumelic As with all purported credentials here, I am an agnostic on principle. You, of course, are free to proceed on your own assumptions, but rest assured that if you're happy, then I'm happy. Here's a clue as to my point (which I wouldn't dignify with the word *rhetorical*): in the title of the question, look for a word that is repeated three times further on.

Comment: Anything that can be misunderstood will be misunderstood.

Comment: @ab2 And half the time, willfully so. Alas, this is the human condition, and one to which I am not immune. I choose not to thereby fetter myself.

Comment: @deadrat I am also trying to work out the purpose or intent in your answer. I tried following-up on your clue, *in the title of the question, look for a word that is repeated three times further on*, and I couldn't find such a word. Here're the counts of all the words in the title, including that first titular instance, so far as I can tell:  `there:3, to:3, this:3, is:2, frivolity:2, be:1, no:1, end-of-year:1, year:1`. There is no word which has a count of 4 (once in the title and 3 more times thereafter), and the ones with 3 are not illuminating...

Comment: @DanBron Just in case your comment isn't a piece of ironic commentary. -- Title: *end-of-year **frivolity***, Question: *spurt of **frivolity***, Answer (@-Mari-LouA): *frolic and **frivolity***, Answer(mine): ***Frivolity**?* Think you can take it from there?

Comment: Ah, you catenated all the answers with question, that seems frivolous ;)

Comment: @DanBron You got it! It only *seems* frivolous.

Comment: @ab2: "Anything that can be misunderstood will be misunderstood."  What do you mean by that?   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @Scott It is one of the many ways of expressing Murphy's Law.

Comment: @ab2 I was being ironic.

Comment: @Scott I slap my forehead in dismay!  Congratulations, you have won the subtlety hat.